# python excel openpyxl insert_rows style error

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

[image]

python excel openpyxl insert_rows style error.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('E:/1.xlsx')
shell = wb.active
shell.insert_rows(7, 5);
wb.save('mergetest.xlsx')
```

I would like to know, if it is possible to insert a new row using openpyxl. 
If already such option or function calls available, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. What is the error you are encountering?

Comment: You obviously can insert new rows as your code does this. You will have to unmerge and remerge any relevant cell ranges yourself.